# Making a 3x3 table for Android

Tags: android, layout, grid

I am very new at developing for android.

I am having a difficult time at making a 3x3 table(TicTacToe table) that looks the way I want it to.

I want the buttons all to be spread out evenly but whenever I try messing with Table/Grid/Linear Layouts they all wind up looking either really big or really small.

http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lcirl6ba4x1qzd2hd.png

I want it to look similar to this. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to each of the buttons, so that they have the same weight:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```